# TFS - order of automata tests to execute

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, functional-testing, system-testing

Supposing I have system tests: A and B, where A includes a record to a database, B tries to modify it. When A fails, B will fail as well. A and B are written as "unit tests" (test methods), A and B are tests cases in TFS as well, automated, linked to these "unit tests". I put them on a test plan, test suite, both of them. I want to execute them with the "Run Functional Tests" step.

How can I tell TFS to execute them in the right order?

What is the best practice to develop tests like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could created an ordered test, which is a container that holds other tests and guarantees that tests run in a specific order.

How to create an ordered test, you could refer this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631(v=vs.120).aspx).

In TFS, you could follow below steps to run ordered test:

1. Add an Order Test file in your test project and use it to define the
   testing order.
2. In your build definition, add a *Run Functional Tests* task. Change
   the Test Assembly like the picture below.
3. In the Test Drop location I have the complete Project, and in the
   Executions folder I have the ordered test.  hope it helps

   [image]

---

**Update**

[It's able to order for manual tests](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/4147125-enable-changing-the-order-of-test-cases-on-the-web), however not able for automated  test. If you need the ordering support for automated tests, please vote on this user voice item:

> ***enable changing the order of test cases on the web gui and let them be tested in this order for automated tests***
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13489221-enable-changing-the-order-of-test-cases-on-the-web

Comment: It is based on "test assembly",  I want to execute a test suite, which contains an "unordered" set of test cases, linked to testmethods. I need to order the executions, but what to execute - it is determined by the test suite. 

More interesting - when B depends on A, but A is not selected in the test suite - it must be executed as well (selected or not) before B to execute B properly.

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak Sorry for this,  for ordering of manual tests case is  available, however it's not able with automated tests for now. You could take a look at the use voice here and vote for it. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13489221-enable-changing-the-order-of-test-cases-on-the-web