# Targeting NUnit Playlist while running tests through TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nunit, nunit-console

We have a TFS build definition that kicks off NUnit tests tagged with the 'Regression' test category. This uses the NUnit console runners annotation of

```
where cat = 'Regression'
```

However, we have multiple different environments where some tests will fail in one environment, they will pass in the other. We have not made much use of the Playlist feature, because I can not find a way to target a playlist when running remotely on TFS. Does anyone know how this can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way of specifying this/playlist in the TFS Build Definition for now. A related uservoice:

> **Allow test playlists to be used by TFS build servers**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3853614-allow-test-playlists-to-be-used-by-tfs-build-serve

As a workaround, you could use `.orderedtest` instead of `.playlist`.

Ordered tests can be created and edited in VS2013 and later. The format is otherwise similar to `.playlist` but it contains links to test GUIDs so its more complicated to modify programmatically.

TFS is able  to run orderedtest in build pipeline, how to achieve this you could refer below links:

- [TFS - order of automata tests to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275722/tfs-order-of-automata-tests-to-execute?rq=1)
- [How to use Vnext build: ordered tests, distribute test, collect results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/711c1f98-2d58-4b9b-805b-204ce6cc4d45/how-to-use-vnext-build-ordered-tests-distribute-test-collect-results?forum=tfsbuild)